# Error while uploading images with EasyMDE

Tags: django

I am using EasyMDE text editor on my Notemaking website, but for some reason, the uploadImage functionality doesn't work.

This is how I instantiate EasyMDE.

```
var easyMDE = new EasyMDE({
    autofocus: true,
    autorefresh: true,
    spellChecker: false,
    minHeight: '180px',
    uploadImage:true,
});
```

Can some one help me fix this issue or point me in the right direction of how to solve it?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for a PHP method but this is what I got :
https://github.com/Ionaru/easy-markdown-editor/pull/71

Edit:-
I figured it out in PHP
You need to also set the "imageUploadEndpoint" value to another file and save your image and print json.
This is how I did in PHP.

Client-Side:

```
var easyMDE = new EasyMDE({
uploadImage:true,
imageUploadEndpoint: 'upload.php'
});
```

Server-Side(in upload.php):

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
header('Content-Type: application/json');
//logic for saving the file
if(image_saving_successful)
{
    $url = the_filepath_for_the_image_saved
    echo '{"data": {"filePath": "'.$url.'"}}';
    http_response_code(200);
    exit;
}else{
    echo '{"error": "your_error_message"}';
    http_response_code(400);
    exit;
}

}else{
header('location: index.php');
exit;
}
?>
```

There are different response code for different error messages. Check Readme.md